# How to deal with jms message consumer with DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE on exception

Tags: jms, spring-jms, tibco

I am consuming messages from tibco queue, with `session transacted true` i am seeing a throughput of 13 msgs/sec, with `session transacted as false` and `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` ack mode is see a throughput of 160 msgs/sec which is promissing but when there is exception thrown in application then the message is lost.

Can any one suggest me how to deal with this situation where I need high throughput at the same no loss of message on exception.

```
    .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(tibcoConnectionFactory)
            .destination(sourceQueue)
            .configureListenerContainer(spec -> {
                spec.sessionTransacted(false);
                spec.sessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            }))
            .transform(orderTransformer, "transform", e -> e.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor())
            .handle(orderService, "save")
            .get();
```

Comment: What container are you using? You must use a SimpleMLC (not the DefaultMLC) if you are not using transactions. Then you shouldn't lose messages.

Comment: Using spring boot container and also using `CachingConnectionFactory`. And also i need to read the messages in order so only single thread consumer

Answer (score 2):

> `.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(tibcoConnectionFactory)`

will use a default container, which can lose messages if not transacted because the listener is called outside of the `consumer.receive()`.

Use

```
.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(tibcoConnectionFactory, 
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class)
```

instead.

**EDIT**

The error message should have been a clue...

> 2018-05-18 11:38:43.657  WARN 48531 --- [ Session Task-1] o.s.j.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer   : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

So add an error handler...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50413144Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50413144Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "foo" + i);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory, SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class)
                        .destination("foo")
                        .configureListenerContainer(c -> {
                            c.sessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                            c.errorHandler(t -> {
                                if (t instanceof RuntimeException) {
                                    throw (RuntimeException) t;
                                }
                            });
                        }))
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    System.out.println(p);
                    if (p.equals("foo5")) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

}
```

... and `foo5` is delivered over and over again.

Comment: Still the same behavior, i am loosing message from queue in case of sql exception thrown at `orderService` in the above code.

Comment: You need an `ErrorHandler` - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick example response. I can see it working with activeMq as the message is redelivered for 7 times (as the flags `jms_redelivered=true, JMSXDeliveryCount=7` say). But with tibco its not working, is there any flag in the session to set the  number of redeliveries ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? `JMSXDeliveryCount` is a [new JMS 2.0 feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html) but some older brokers implemented it. Giving up after some number of deliveries is not part of the JMS spec but most brokers have some way to configure that behavior. I am not familiar with tibco.

Comment: camel has a concept of `maximumRedeliveries` on exception, i thought there is something in spring integration that i missed. with regards to tibco the above program failed to redeliver when there is an exception, it continued to consume foo6.  when i set `sessionTransacted to true` and `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` the foo5 message is redelivered n number of times.

Comment: With Spring Integration you would have to add `.errorChannel(someErrorChannel())` to the adapter, and check the delivery count in the `payload.failedMessage.headers` and either re-throw or consume/log the failure. We could consider adding built-in support for when the broker does provide that header. I'll open a JIRA issue. What you are describing about Tibco makes no sense; are you sure you changed the container type to simple in that case? Turning on DEBUG logging might help you figure it out.